# React-Native firebase listAll() URLs inside .then()

Tags: url, storage, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to push all the URLs from inside the `.then` into the `imageHolder` array and return the array out of the function eventually, usually it works fine, but not with this not sure why, anyone can help please?

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

export const fetchProfilePicturesRequest = async () => {
  const reference = await storage()
    .ref(`{currentUser}/images`)
    .listAll();

  var imageHolder = [];

  reference.items.map(values => {
     values.getDownloadURL().then((urlValues) => {
      console.log('Holder now is ', imageHolder);
      imageHolder = imageHolder.concat(urlValues);
    });
  });

  return imageHolder;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`values.getDownloadURL()` is Async function so that's why return statement would be called before even `values.getDownloadURL()` return something and so array would be null in that case. You need to put await before `values.getDownloadURL()` like this

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

export const fetchProfilePicturesRequest = async () => {
const reference = await storage()
.ref(`{currentUser}/images`)
.listAll();

var imageHolder = [];

for(let i=0;i<reference.items.length;i++){
   await reference.items[i].getDownloadURL().then((urlValues) => {
      console.log('UrlValue: ', urlValues);
      imageHolder.push(urlValues);
   });
}

console.log('Holder now is ', imageHolder);

return imageHolder;
};
```

Hopefully, this will resolve your problem

Comment: Still doesnt work plus i get the simulator showing this error ```console.error: "JSON value '()' of type NSMutableArray cannot be converted to NSString"```

Comment: Please debug urlValues if they are getting printed correctly. Plus I updated the code

Comment: Same issue remains, ```urlValues``` prints correctly only inside the ```.then``` code block but not outside of it for some reason.

Comment: edited the code, await does not work with the map so I updated map into for loop. Now await should work now

Comment: Great, it works fine now, i didn't know that ```await``` doesn't with inside the ```.map```, thanks you allot